# How to get struct fields and fields type in a compiler plugin?

Tags: rust, rust-compiler-plugin

I want to generate a `HashMap` which use struct fields as key, and use `usize` integer as value.

```
pub struct Article {
    title: String,
    content: String,
    category: String,
    comments: Vec<Comment>
}

pub struct Comment {
    content: String
}
```

My expected output is:

```
{
    title: 0,
    content: 1,
    category: 2
    comments[].content: 3
}
```

My solution is `impl` my trait `FieldsMapping` for both `Article` and `Comment`:

```
pub trait FieldsMapping {
    fn get_fields_map(&self) -> HashMap<String, usize>;
}
```

I want to write a compiler plugin for custom derive `FieldsMapping`.

How I get all fields within compiler plugin? And how can I know that fields type is `Vec` or other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.

Compiler plugins (*i.e.* procedural macros) are expanded before this information exists, so you can't access it.  No, you can't delay expansion until types exist.  No, if you turn it into a lint, you can't generate code, which then defeats the purpose of having a procedural macro.